# What's the max number of 3x3x3 cubes that can be adjacent to a 12x12x6 cuboid?

Tags: geometry

I'm planning a labyrinth game where each room can be as small as 3x3x3 and as large as 12x12x6. To save memory I only want to cull the room you're in plus all adjacent rooms.

So now I need to know the maximum possible number of adjacent rooms. I'm assuming this will occur when your room is 12x12x6 and all adjacent rooms are 3x3x3. I'm also assuming there's **no empty volume between rooms.**

(P.S., caty-corner edges and caty-corner corners do **not** count. For two rooms to be adjacent, their faces must overlap by at least 1 square.)

I can imagine all the small rooms lined up perfectly with the faces of the big center room and get an answer of 16*2 + 8*4 = 64. But of course now we have to shift the small rooms 1 or 2 units in one dimension, or two dimensions, or all three three? I cannot wrap my head around that. I think the answer is 80 if every small room is shifted once in the x and y dimension, but it's hard for me to state that with certitude.

BTW, is there some formula out there relating the min axbxc cuboid with the max AxBxC cuboid?

Answer (score 1):

The two $12\times12$ walls of the large room can be adjacent with at most $5\times5=25$ small rooms each. The four $6\times12$ walls can then be adjacent with at most $2\times5=10$ small rooms (only two of them) or $2\times4=8$ small rooms (the other two). So you can have a maximum of $25\times2+10\times2+8\times2=86$ adjacent small rooms.

Other dispositions are possible, but they all lead to the same number.